# ExpressJS dont find task by ID

Tags: node.js, express, backend

**SOLVED**
need to json.parse it

const tasksBuffer = fs.readFileSync('file_db/tasks.json')
const tasks = JSON.parse(tasksBuffer)

Why When I use the GET method it doesnt get a task/idNumber ??? i have this code that read good all task fromt he file but cant Get only 1 by the ID.
Also I can POST well.

```
app.get('/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {
    const tasksBuffer = fs.readFileSync('file_db/tasks.json')
    const tasks = JSON.parse(tasksBuffer)
    // OLD const tasks = fs.readFileSync('file_db/tasks.json')
    const taskId = req.params.id
    const task = tasks.find((task) => {
        return task.id === taskId
    })
    if (task) {
        res.json(task)
    } else {
        res.status(404).send()
    }
})
```

Comment: `console.log` the `req.params`, check if you are getting the `id`.

Comment: Yes, it is working.
console tell me: { id: '0001' }

Comment: Const task seen to be Undefined when i try to console.log it

Comment: post tasks.json